# Use the augmented Lagrangian method to solve the problem

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Use the augmented Lagrangian method to solve the problem

$ \min \ f(x); f(x)= \|x\|^4, x \in\mathbb R^2 \ $ subject to a constraint $ \  x_1 + x_2- 3 x_3= 2 \ $.

**Answer:**

we have to minimize $ f(x)=\|x\|^4 \ $ subject to the constraint $ \ x_1+x_2-3x_3 =2 \ $ .

Here $ f(x)=f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\|x\|^4=(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)^2 $.

Now , how to set the Lagrangian function $ L(x,\lambda , \rho ) \ $  ?

**I need help in setting up the augmented function .**

Answer (score 0):

We want to minimize
$$
  f
  \colon
  \mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}
  \colon
  (x_1,x_2,x_3) \mapsto \left(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2\right)^2
$$
subject to
$$
  g(x) = x_1 + x_2 - 3x_3 -2 = 0.
$$
Because there is no inequality constraint and only one equality constraint, then the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$ has the form
$$
  \mathcal{L}\colon \mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow\mathbb{R}
  \colon
  (x_1,x_2,x_3,\lambda)
  \mapsto
  f(x_1,x_2,x_3) + \lambda g(x_1, x_2, x_3),
$$
thus
$$
  \mathcal{L}(x_1,x_2,x_3,\lambda)=\left(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2\right) + \lambda(x_1+x_2-3x_3-2).
$$

Answer (score 0):

You want to 
$$ min\ \ f(x) \\ h(x) = 0 $$

You can use Augmented function like this:

$$ 0.5 * || h(x) ||^2 $$

Augmented Lagrangian would then be:

$$ f(x) + \lambda*h(x) + \rho*0.5*|| h(x) ||^2 $$